# Redirecting from POST not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created an API using node and exposed one method which will be executed upon POST request.

From that method I am returning

```
res.redirect(redirectUrl);
```

to redirect to a url.

But when this response is sent back to the browser, it's redirecting again to the API as POST request, looking for the `redirectUrl` under the API itself.

It might be some stupid mistake but I can't get rid of this. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: can we use plain javascript in node window.location.href="www.google.com"

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP response status code [`302` Found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) is a common way of performing a redirection.

An HTTP response with this status code will additionally provide a URL in the Location header field. The User Agent (e.g. a web browser) is invited by a response with this code to make a second, otherwise identical, request, to the new URL specified in the Location field. The HTTP/1.0 specification ([RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945)) defines this code, and gives it the description phrase "Moved Temporarily".

Source : Wikipedia

```
res.statusCode = 302;
res.setHeader("Location", '/Url');
res.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [How do I redirect to another page like google using Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789526/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-page-like-google-using-nodejs/45811342#45811342). I answered for this question. You can redirect using post method with the api.After data you posted response will be redirected to which you want to redirect.

Look at this code

```
url.route('/num')
.post(function(req,res){
      shortUrl.create(req.body,function(err,url){
if (err) return console.log(error); 
        //return res.send(url);
        res.redirect('https://www.google.com');
     });

})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake, it was simply the procotol missing from the redirect URL